# How to block existing dates before inserting into database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, duplicates

I want to block the duplicate dates before inserting it into database.If a week with the same date is already exist in the database,when selecting the same date it should pop-up with the error message "this dates are already chosen".

Example:
If Week 1 is 1.1.2015 to 5.1.2015 stored in database and when Week 2 is also selecting the same date from 1.1.2015 to 5.1.2015,it should give the error message.

How to accomplish this,suggest some ideas.

This is my database.[image]

I am using SQL database.Where the selected dates are stored in "datedif" column in database. With the "daywk" column I'm selecting the dates by week wise and displayed in grid.

I want to block the duplicate date when inserting into "datedif" column.

my code so far.

```
 using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=Z:\NewTimeTable\NewTimeTable\App_Data\Admindetail.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
        {

            var fromdate = DateTime.Parse(txtfromdate.Text);
            var todate = DateTime.Parse(txttodate.Text);
            var datedif1 = (todate - fromdate).Days;

            var sqlInsert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO datelist ([datedif],[batch],[daywk],[semester],[weekbatch],[subject],[facultyname],[facultyid],[WeekMonth])  VALUES  (@datedif,@batch,@daywk,@semester,@weekbatch,@subject,@facultyname,@facultyid,@weekMonth)", con2);
            var sqlParamater  = sqlInsert.Parameters.Add("@datedif", SqlDbType.Date);
            var sqlParameter1 = sqlInsert.Parameters.Add("@batch", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            var sqlParameter2 = sqlInsert.Parameters.Add("@daywk", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            var sqlParameter3 = sqlInsert.Parameters.Add("@semester", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            var sqlParameter4 = sqlInsert.Parameters.Add("@weekbatch", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            var sqlParameter5 = sqlInsert.Parameters.Add("@subject", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            var sqlParameter6 = sqlInsert.Parameters.Add("@facultyname", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            var sqlParameter7 = sqlInsert.Parameters.Add("@facultyid", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            var sqlParameter8 = sqlInsert.Parameters.Add("@WeekMonth", SqlDbType.NVarChar);



            con2.Open();
            for (var i = 0; i <= datedif1; i++)
            {
                var consecutiveDate = fromdate.AddDays(i);

                sqlParamater.Value = consecutiveDate;
                sqlParameter1.Value = batch1;
                sqlParameter2.Value = dayweek;
                sqlParameter3.Value = semester;
                sqlParameter4.Value = weekbatch;
                sqlParameter5.Value = subject;
                sqlParameter6.Value = faculty;
                sqlParameter7.Value = facultyid;
                sqlParameter8.Value = weekmonth;

                sqlInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
                con2.Close();

            }
        }
```

Comment: put some more description

Comment: how does one choose a date? datepicker? or you just enter it manually?

Comment: I'm creating the timetable in week wise with date-picker.when the week1 is already storing with some dates in database and when week2 is also selecting with the same dates it shouldn't insert into database and give the error pop-up.

Comment: one can choose with the date-picker

Comment: Write a query that returns whether there is already a week with the same date and display the error message if the returned value is true.

This would be about as specific as is your question.

You really have to add more information. What have you tried? What database are you using? How does your database and object models look like? etc...

Comment: In your for loop you should create elements that you put into a List, for example, then you can simply use Linq with Distinct() to filter out duplicates on the field you need to be unique (and then write to the DB).

Answer (score 1):

```
    List persons = new List();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2014;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT BusinessEntityID AS ID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName FROM Person.Person", connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // Check is the reader has any rows at all before starting to read.
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {

            throw new ApplicationExcetion("Data is duplicated");    

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

before insert into database. just query first.
if query have exist data(duplicated data). then throw exception

Comment: see my below another reply